# Prolog procedure does not exist (cant run rules in prolog)

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and using the SWISH SWI online PROLOG website. https://swish.swi-prolog.org/
I am trying a really basic program:

```
a('jae').
b('lii').
c('jackson').
happy(A):-sings(A).
happy(B):-dances(B).
goToPlay(C):-free(C).
```

trying to run *happy(jae).* gives the following error

```
procedure `sings(A)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      happy(A)
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If submit the *goal*

```
happy(jae).
```

Then rule

```
happy(A) :- sings(A).
```

applies, which means that the next goal to be solved is

```
sings(A).
```

with `A` = `jae`.

Unfortunately the one-argument predicate `sings/1` is nowhere to be found, so you get the same error as for a missing procedure in another programming language.

You have to define `sings/1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem!!